# Firebase cloud Parsing error: Unexpected token admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

so on "points" class created, i'm finding the user and updating its points with 100 (num value) but i keep getting that referuserRef unexpected
this is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
      const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();

exports.pointsCreated = functions.firestore
        .document('points/{pointsid}')
        .onCreate((snap, context) => {
            
            const newValue = snap.data();
            if (newValue['type'] !== null) {
                if (newValue['type'] === 'refer') {
                    const referuserRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(newValue['user']); //this is where i get the error
                    console.log("referuserRef");
                    console.log(referuserRef);
                    const referuserDoc = await referuserRef.get()
                    if (referuserDoc.exists) {
                        referuserRef.set({ points: Number(referuserDoc.data()['points']) + 100 }, { merge: true });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

here's the package.json and .eslintrc.json has "ecmaVersion": 7 (i tried 8 too but it gave me same error everytime i tried

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update following your comment

You need to correctly manage the life cycle of your Cloud Function, by waiting for the asynchronous Firebase methods calls to complete before indicating to the Cloud Function platform that it can clean up your function. See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.

So, the following should do the trick:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
admin.initializeApp();

exports.pointsCreated = functions.firestore
    .document('points/{pointsid}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        try {
            const newValue = snap.data();
            if (newValue['type'] !== null) {
                if (newValue['type'] === 'refer') {
                    const referuserRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(newValue['user']);
                    const referuserDoc = await referuserRef.get();
                    if (referuserDoc.exists) {
                        await referuserRef.set({ points: FieldValue.increment(100) }, { merge: true });
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // ...
            return null;
        }

    });
```

Note the use of [`FieldValue`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html) to increment the value of the `points` field.

---

Old answer:

It seems that you don't load the Cloud Functions SDK. You should do as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// ...
```

Comment: Can you share the `package.json` file which is in the `functions` directory?

Comment: Hmm... I don't see where could be the problem... I'll delete my answer in 10 minutes. Note however that you are using await without declaring the function async, and also , you are not correctly managing the life cycle of yoru Cloud Function. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions as it is very important.

Comment: if i remove await, it deploys but does not execute.... "Error: could not handle the request" on api request

Comment: it directly goes to catch error with "TypeError: snap.data is not a function "

Comment: I would suggest you start with a brand new Firebase project. I've just tested the code from my answer and it does work, correctly incrementing the field in the existing user doc.